# Django 1.3 static files placed in application dirs

Tags: django

I'm using Django 1.3 and the static files in app is confusing.
What I was doing:
1) Set the

```
STATIC_ROOT = as path to directory 'static' in my project
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

2) Serve in my urls.py

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns(
        '',
        url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT}),
    )
```

3) Place css and js files into the folder 'static' in my application directory.
So I got such directories tree:

```
my_project/
    main_app/
        static/
            css/
                style.css
            js/
    secondary_app/
        static/
            foldername/
                file.css
```

4) I added both of this applications to INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py file. 
And now in my template when I write follow line:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/style.css" type="text/css" />
```

Django successfuly finds my css file in directory

```
my_project/main_app/static/css/
```

and plugs in style.css
But when I write

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}foldername/file.css" type="text/css" />
```

Django doesn't plug in this file.

So my question: What I'm doing wrong? Why I cant plug in my css file from secondary_app directory?
What I have to tell you more about this situation?

Comment: You have two directories called "static". Which one does `STATIC_ROOT` point to again?

Comment: In the docs on official site I read that developers able to put static files into 'static/' subdirectory of your application.  Am I wrong? [link](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#managing-static-files)

Comment: By the way if I rename secondary_app/static/foldername/ , which contains my css file, to secondary_app/static/css/ Django plugs in css file successfully. I dont know why... Does anybody can explain this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The idea behind that is that you ship all your apps with their own static files under `app/static`.

Once you deploy an app in a project, running `python manage.py collectstatic` will copy all static files found thanks to `STATICFILES_FINDERS` setting (which contains a finder looking for a `static` dir in each installed app by default) within your `STATIC_ROOT` directory then will be served via `STATIC_URL`

The development server handles that `STATIC_URL` pattern when in `DEBUG` mode but this is an interesting read : [Serving static files in production](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-in-production)

Comment: You mean each time we add a static file into the dev environment we have to run a collectstatic ?

Comment: @Glide: No. If you have collectstatic happening but don't want it: remove the Apache alias and add `staticfiles_urlpatterns` to your urls and turn debug on. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#static-file-development-view (at the bottom).