# Why can't I get my static dir to work with django 1.3?

Tags: python, django, web, static, url-pattern

This problem is very simple, but I just can't figure it out

added to my urlpatterns

```
url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': '/home/user/www/site/static'})
```

where my main.css is : /home/user/www/site/static/css/main.css

when I access http://localhost:8000/static/

I get: 404: Directory indexes are not allowed here.

when I access http://localhost:8000/static/css/main.css

I get: 404: 'css/main.css' could not be found

What am I doing wrong?

Fixed it:

```
url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT } ),
```

in settings.py

```
# Absolute path to the directory static files should be collected to.
# Don't put anything in this directory yourself; store your static files
# in apps' "static/" subdirectories and in STATICFILES_DIRS.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(CURRENT_PATH, 'static') #=='/home/user/www/site/static'

# URL prefix for static files.
# Example: "http://media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_URL = '/mystatic/'
```

As you can see the only thing I really changed was from STATIC_URL = '/static/' to STATIC_URL = '/mystatic/'

note: when I got to http://localhost:8000/mystatic... I get the same errors as above

I thought that STATIC_URL was supposed to be '/static/' so that you could use {{ STATIC_URL }} in your templates...  I really don't understand why this fix worked and why I had to make the change that I did....

Why does this work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are using the built-in development webserver (i.e. run it with `manage.py runserver`), Django will take care of static files while in development.

Please note that `STATIC_ROOT` is the path where Django collects static files in, rather than the path that it serves files from.  You should not maintain `STATIC_ROOT` yourself!  You can read more on that in [the Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/static-files/).

In general, you don't need to add `django.views.static.serve` to your urls, with the built-in server.

The static files should be placed elsewhere, besides `STATIC_ROOT`.  You can place them either in the `myapp/static` path (i.e. under the individual app static file).  You can also dedicate static folder for the entire project (e.g. `/path/to/project/proj_settings`) and update `STATICFILES_DIRS` in `settings.py` to be:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
    os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'proj_static'),
)
```

Then you can place your `css/main.css` file in `/proj_static/css/main.css`.  Django built-in webserver will server `/static/` from there.

While in production, you should collect all the static files in `STATIC_ROOT`, by running `manage.py collectstatic`.  Then you can serve that folder directly through your webserver (e.g. nginx, Apache), rather than through Django.

Comment: @notnoop How do you reference a file that is automatically included in the `myapp/static` directory? i.e. does `myapp/static/file1` appear simply as `STATIC_URL/file1`?

Answer (score 1):

mainly two step:

1. check STATIC_ROOT path:

   Does the file exist?   /home/user/www/site/static/css/main.css 
   if not, you shoud run  "python manage.py collectstatic"  to copy static file to STATIC_ROOT path
   if "collectstatic" can't copy css files to STATIC_ROOT path,  then shoud check source css path in "STATICFILES_DIRS"
2. in develope env, (use runserver to start web server),  make sure:

   a) settings.py:   INSTALLED_APPS  include: 'django.contrib.staticfiles'
   b) urls.py:       urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()

I guess you not config step 2.b .
your method should ok, but it is hardcoded,

```
url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT } ),
```

In django's document it already be mentioned:

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set up STATIC_URL in settings.py

In your case it have to be

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Comment: STATIC_URL is already set to that, I also have STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(CURRENT_PATH, 'static/') which means STATIC_ROOT = /home/user/www/site/static/, confirm this when I printed it in html

Comment: I'm not sure but try write it without slash: STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(CURRENT_PATH, 'static') and also the better way is import this variable into urls.py and use it there.

Comment: you can read my question about this [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5580902/django-1-3-static-files-placed-in-application-dirs) maybe something will help you. As usual I place static files into app dirs and it's okay.

Comment: I've chosen to use on static folder in the main dir and then subfolders in the static folder to split the files up